# Does this temporary reference survive long enough?

Tags: c++, temporary

In

```
template <typename T>
T const & foo(T const & dflt) 
  { return /* ... */ ? /* ... */ : dflt; }

int x = foo(5);
```

Does the reference to temporary "survive" until it's assigned to x?

(I know it survives the duration of the foo() call, but the assignment makes me hesitate)

The code in question has some legitimate uses for relying on const references here, i.e. I would need two separate functions

```
T const & foo_cr(T  const & dflt);
T const & foo_v(T dflt);
```

which I want to avoid (just relying on different signatures wiht the same name seems a bit risky to me.)

Comment: What does `... ? ... : dflt;` that supposed to mean? 0_o

Comment: `...` in this context is "code that is irrelevant to the question. I've changed it to comments, maybe that's clearer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Does the reference to temporary "survive" until it's assigned to x?

Generally, yes. If `foo` returns `dflt`, that reference (to a temporary 5) is valid until the end of the full-expression it was created in, that means, until after the initialization.

C++03, 12.2/3:

> When an implementation introduces a temporary object of a class that
>   has a non-trivial constructor (12.1), it shall ensure that a
>   constructor is called for the temporary object. Similarly, the
>   destructor shall be called for a temporary with a non-trivial
>   destructor (12.4). Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in
>   evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the
>   point where they were created. This is true even if that evaluation
>   ends in throwing an exception.

More comes in 12.2/4 and 12.2/5, especially the exceptions of this rule.

I can't see what happens when it returns the `...` you left out, but I guess you weren't asking about this.

Comment: It currently is not specified that the store to "x" is part of the full expression. See http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=9783 , however strongly desired by both the committee and (hopefully) users. But independent of that, it is already specified by the spec that the *read* of the reference returned by `foo` (lvalue-to-rvalue) is part of the full expression. See 1.9p10 and its trailing example.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Yes, the ... case is safe - I just excluded it (reference to an element of a collection passed by reference as additional parameter)